# Vertical space between list items in OPmac

Tags: lists, plain-tex, opmac

I want to add some space between items in a list:

```
\input opmac

\def\itemhook{\vskip 7pt\relax}

\begmulti 2
\begitems
* $y=3x^2=x=2$.
* $y=3+8x-x^2-x^3$.
* $y=7-18x-3x^2+4x^3$.
* $y=6-15x+18x^2-4x^3$.
\enditems
\endmulti

\bye
```

Unfortunately, the last item has additional space after it making the columns unbalanced.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Does this helps: `\def\iiskip{\vskip 7pt\relax}`?

Comment: @JagathAR - sorry, no that seems to be for space before and after the list, not between items.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that your `\vskip7pt` is breaking point after the second item and it is discarded. The second column includes `\iiskip` (default `\medskip`, 6pt plus...minus...) after fourth item and `\vfil` is appedned here by `\endmulti`. You see `\medskip` after fourth item but nothing after second item in your illustration image. The `\parskip0pt plus1pt` is stretched between first and second item. Note, that the first glue before item list (from `\iiskip`) is discarded by `\begmulti`.

If you set `\begmulti 2 \def\iiskip{}` Now, only `\vfil` is after fourth item and it is slightly stretched. But first column stretches in `\parskip`, so there is no exactly balancing. The final solution is to set `\parskip` to a value without stretchability:

```
\input opmac

\def\itemhook{\vskip 7pt\relax}

\begmulti 2 \def\iiskip{}\parskip=0pt
\begitems
* $y=3x^2=x=2$.
* $y=3+8x-x^2-x^3$.
* $y=7-18x-3x^2+4x^3$.
* $y=6-15x+18x^2-4x^3$.
\enditems
\endmulti

\bye
```

Comment: When I change font it happens again:
`\input opmac
\input fontfam

\margins/1 a5 (1,1,1,1)in

\fontfam[tg schola]

\begitems \style n
\begmulti 2 \def\iiskip{}\parskip=0pt
* $x^2+x-3$.
* ${1\over 3}x^3+3x+1$.
* $x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$.
* ${1\over 3}x^6+{1\over 4}x^4+2x^2+3$.
* $x^5-4x^4+x^2-4x$.
* $x^7+7x^5+21X^3-14x$.
* $x^4-x^2+4x-1$.
* $3+2x^2+7x^4-11x^5$.
* $ax^3+bx^2+cx+f$.
* $a+bx^2+cx^4+ex^5.$
\endmulti
\enditems

\bye`

Comment: The balancing works perfectly only for equidistant lines. The `\endmulti` adds `\vfil` after the last item (because there can be odd number of items when `\begmulti 2` for example). If you adds two fractions to the second column (like they are in the first) then you can find the good balancing. Or advance `\baselineskip`. Or another method: remove `\vfil` and add stretchable glue between items. I. e. remove `\parskip=0pt` and do  `\def\tmp#1\vfil{} \expandafter\tmp\endmulti`.

Comment: So is it safe to say that of the possible solutions, the most reliable for lining up the baselines of the last items in the columns is to use `\def\tmp#1\vfil{} \expandafter\tmp\endmulti` ? Are there any other possible issues with it?